# How to implement interactive notifications ios8

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8

I'm creating a timed todo list app in which users can start a timer from a lock screen notification by swiping to reveal a start button. This is a new feature shown in iOS 8 but there is little documentation showing how to implement this feature. 
Can anyone show how I would go about setting up the 'start' action and the block of code which runs when this is pressed? If the app were closed would this feature still work?

Comment: Do you found any workaround for your question?

Comment: Watching the developer videos showed me how to implement the basic notification action code. Really helpful video. In order to workout the end time of the timer I used the time the user interacted with the start notification and added the duration of the timer and used this to set the fire date of a new notification.

Comment: Please provide with sample or git link to implement. Thanks

Comment: Refer to this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929665/features-supported-by-ios8-interactive-notification/25930069#25930069 for more info please visit...https://github.com/sgup77/SGNotification

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929665/how-to-implement-ios8-interactive-notification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to know more about interactive notifications- a new feature in iOS 8 go to the below link

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/

and then go to the section "What's New in iOS Notifications"

Answer (score 42):

@Shubhendu thanks for the link. For those of you who don't want to have to sit through the video, here's a quick recap of what you need to do in order to include interactive notifications in you application.

- Define all the actions that the user may execute from your app's notifications. These actions are created using the [UIMutableUserNotificationAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIMutableUserNotificationAction_class/) class.

  ```
  UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
  action.identifier = @"ACTION_ID"; // The id passed when the user selects the action
  action.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Title",nil); // The title displayed for the action
  action.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground; // Choose whether the application is launched in foreground when the action is clicked
  action.destructive = NO; // If YES, then the action is red
  action.authenticationRequired = NO; // Whether the user must authenticate to execute the action
  ```
- Place these actions into categories. Each category defines a group of actions that a user may execute from a notification. These categories are created using [UIMutableUserNotificationCategory](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIMutableUserNotificationCategory_class/).

  ```
  UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *category = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
  category.identifier = @"CATEGORY_ID"; // Identifier passed in the payload
  [category setActions:@[action] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault]; // The context determines the number of actions presented (see documentation)
  ```
- Register the categories in the settings. Note that registering the categories doesn't replace asking for user permission to send remote notifications,using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications]`

  ```
  NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:category, nil];
  NSUInteger types = UIUserNotificationTypeNone; // Add badge, sound, or alerts here
  UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUSerNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:categories];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
  ```
- Send the identifier of the category in the notification payload.

  ```
  {
      "aps":{
          "alert":"Here's a notification",
          ...
          "category":"CATEGORY_ID"
      }
  }
  ```
- Handle user actions in the app delegate by implementing the UIApplicationDelegate protocol methods: 
  `application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:completionHandler:` for remote notifications 
  `application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:`  for local notifications

Comment: Thanks a lot for the description of the notification payload!

Comment: Is it possible to have 3 Interactive Notification Actions ?

Comment: how to handle remote notifications on lick screen

Answer (score 8):

STEP 1:

```
NSString * const NotificationCategoryIdent  = @"ACTIONABLE";
NSString * const NotificationActionOneIdent = @"ACTION_ONE";
NSString * const NotificationActionTwoIdent = @"ACTION_TWO";

- (void)registerForNotification {

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action1;
    action1 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [action1 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
    [action1 setTitle:@"Action 1"];
    [action1 setIdentifier:NotificationActionOneIdent];
    [action1 setDestructive:NO];
    [action1 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action2;
    action2 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [action2 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
    [action2 setTitle:@"Action 2"];
    [action2 setIdentifier:NotificationActionTwoIdent];
    [action2 setDestructive:NO];
    [action2 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory;
    actionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
    [actionCategory setIdentifier:NotificationCategoryIdent];
    [actionCategory setActions:@[action1, action2] 
                    forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:actionCategory];
    UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|
                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound|
                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);

    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings;
    settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types
                                                 categories:categories];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}
```

**STEP 2:**
To send this type of notification simply add the category to the payload.

```
{  
    "aps" : { 
        "alert"    : "Pull down to interact.",
        "category" : "ACTIONABLE"
    }
}
```

STEP 3:
Use this method

```
application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:completionHand
ler:

[application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:
 -> For LOCAL Notification]

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:NotificationActionOneIdent]) {

        NSLog(@"You chose action 1.");
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:NotificationActionTwoIdent]) {   

        NSLog(@"You chose action 2.");
    }    
    if (completionHandler) {

        completionHandler();
    }
}
```

1.Refer link: [Obj C tutorial](https://nrj.io/simple-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8)

2.[Swift Code Tutorial here](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/interactive-notifications-with-notification-actions/)

Comment: All of this is deprecated.

Comment: not working in ios 11, button not show. Can you provice in ios 10+?

Answer (score 3):

For ios10 Actionable push use this

```
 UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
| UNAuthorizationOptionSound
    | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
     requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
     completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
     }
     ];
UNNotificationAction *ok = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:@"OK"
                                                                           title:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)
                                                                         options:UNNotificationActionOptionForeground];
    UNNotificationAction *cancel = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:@"CANCEL"
                                                                               title:NSLocalizedString(@"CANCEL", nil)
                                                                             options:UNNotificationActionOptionForeground];
    NSArray *buttons = @[ ok, cancel ];

    // create a category for message failed
    UNNotificationCategory *buttonsAction = [UNNotificationCategory categoryWithIdentifier:@"ACTION_BUTTON"
                                                                                    actions:buttons
                                                                          intentIdentifiers:@[]
                                                                                    options:UNNotificationCategoryOptionCustomDismissAction];
NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:buttonsAction, nil];

    // registration
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setNotificationCategories:categories];
```

Answer (score 2):

With iOS 8 came an exciting new API for creating interactive notifications. These allow you to provide additional functionality to your users outside of your application.

Let’s get started. There are 3 new classes in iOS 8 which are needed: `UIUserNotificationSettings, UIUserNotificationCategory, UIUserNotificationAction` and their mutable counterparts.

Instead of simply registering for notification types (sounds, banners, alerts) you can now also register for custom notification categories and actions. Categories describe a custom type of notification that your application sends and contains actions that a user can perform in response. For example you receive a notification that someone followed you on a social network. In response you might want to follow them back or ignore.

```
NSString * const NotificationCategoryIdent  = @"ACTIONABLE";
NSString * const NotificationActionOneIdent = @"ACTION_ONE";
NSString * const NotificationActionTwoIdent = @"ACTION_TWO";

- (void)registerForNotification {

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action1;
    action1 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [action1 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
    [action1 setTitle:@"Action 1"];
    [action1 setIdentifier:NotificationActionOneIdent];
    [action1 setDestructive:NO];
    [action1 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action2;
    action2 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
    [action2 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
    [action2 setTitle:@"Action 2"];
    [action2 setIdentifier:NotificationActionTwoIdent];
    [action2 setDestructive:NO];
    [action2 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

    UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory;
    actionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
    [actionCategory setIdentifier:NotificationCategoryIdent];
    [actionCategory setActions:@[action1, action2] 
                    forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:actionCategory];
    UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|
                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound|
                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);

    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings;
    settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types
                                                 categories:categories];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}
```

//JSON payload:

```
{
"aps" : { 
    "alert"    : "Pull down to interact.",
    "category" : "ACTIONABLE"
    }
}
```

Now to handle the actions the user selects, there are 2 new methods on the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol:\

```
application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:
application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:completionHandler:
```

These methods will get called, in the background, when the user selects an action from your push notification.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:NotificationActionOneIdent]) {

        NSLog(@"You chose action 1.");
    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:NotificationActionTwoIdent]) {   

        NSLog(@"You chose action 2.");
    }    
    if (completionHandler) {

        completionHandler();
    }
}
```